# Comparing two Int variables with room/margin for error

Tags: c#, java, int, compare

```
public void checkForCollision () {
          
  int headX = cells[0].x; 
  int headY = cells[0].y;
  int noOfParts = nPoints;
  
  for(int i = 1; i <noOfParts;i++)
  {
     int tempX = cells[i].x;
     int tempY = cells[i].y;
     
     
      if(tempX == headX && tempY == headY){
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Head hit body");
          //EndGameCollectScore etc.
        }
  }
       
}
```

EDIT: 'Cells[]' is an array of type Point AND noOfParts is just how many segments the snake has

#### main Question

With the above code I'm trying to compare tempX to headX but i would like to have a sort of margin for error e.g. +-5 but am unsure how to accomplish this, my reasoning behind this is i'm thinking maybe the x and Y variables might be a few digits apart so if i have the radius of one of the segment of the snake (explanation of 'snake' in Alternate below) then if i'm right and the values are a tiny bit off it should still come back positive.

### **OR**

#### Alternative

if anyone can suggest a better way for doing this? Basically it's for a Snake game and headX and headY is the head of the snake and the remaining X and Y variables in Cells is the body, and I'm attempting to compare if the head hits the body.

I tested it and it seemed to work but after i tested it again it seems it will only pick up the collision if i make the snake double back on itself for a few squares. e.g. IF i cross the body perpendicular it will not detect the collision.

Also i am fairly certain that this method is called after each block the snake moves.

Cheers,
Shane.

**P.S Running of very little sleep and way too much sugar in my blood, If you need further clarification because the above doesn't make alot of sense let me know.**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
int eps = 5;
if (Math.abs(tempX - headX) <= eps && Math.abs(tempY - headY) <= eps) { 
    // ...
}
```

Comment: simple yet it works, thanks.

I'm still having the problem of the snake being able to go through itself sometimes however I think this may be another issue.

Answer (score 3):

To check if two points are within a `delta` from each other, compute the distance between them. You can avoid going into the square root territory by using squares, like this:

```
int distSq = (tempX-headX)*(tempX-headX) + (tempY-headY)*(tempY-headY);
int minDist = 5;
if (distSq < minDist*minDist) {
    // too close
}
```

Comment: I'm sure this will also work and i'm greatful you wrote up this answer however I'm going to vote 2kay's answer as the accepted simply due to the simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your snake looks, but if it has a complex shape, looking for a hit can be expensive in terms of speed. You can speed up collision detection if you can do a quick test, to see if a collision is possible at all. You can do this by using a bounding box. You would have to keep track of minimum and maximum x and y positions of the snake body. Only if a coordinate lies within these boundaries you would take account of the exact shape of the snake. How this has to be done depends on how the snake is represented. Check for each tile or each pixel the snake is made of or possibly check if the coordinate is within a polygon, if the snake outline is defined by a polygon. (I'm not going to explain how this works here, but you will find algorithms if you google a bit.)

If you need to calculate the distance to another point (the snake head), you can use different metrics for this. If only horizontal and vertical movements are possible within the game, the so called Manhattan or taxi distance can be used: `d = |x1-x0| + |y1-y0|`. It consists of adding the x and y distances, or you can use the maximum of both distances: `d = Max(|x1-x0|, |y1-y0|)` (correponds to 2kay's approach).

If you need the exact distance, apply the Pythagorean formula. In order to compare the distance with the error margin, you don't need to calculate the square root. Instead compare the square of the distance with the square of the error margin. This saves time. `(x1-x0)^2 + (y1-y0)^2 < error_margin^2`.